# Ansible: Connect to Nodes without DNS or /etc/hosts" resolution

Tags: ansible

I have a Dynamic Inventory Script which outputs the following.

```
"NODE_A": {
        "inventory_hostname": "10.0.2.6",
        "inventory_lparname": "NODE_A"
}
```

The Nodes are not resolvable via DNS or something as this Network is some kind of isolated "Management" LAN.
Until now i had a Play running which modifies the local /etc/hosts  File to enable Name Resolution. 
As the Ansible Controller is going to move to an foreign Machine, this is not possible anymore.
So the big question is how to proceed. How do i instruct Ansible to connect to the IP Adress instead of the Hostname, repectively can i use "inventory_hostname" instead of "ansible_hostname" as Connection String, but keep the Hostname displayed in the Play Recap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i instruct Ansible to connect to the IP Adress instead of the Hostname, repectively can i use "inventory_hostname" instead of "ansible_hostname" as Connection String, but keep the Hostname displayed in the Play Recap?

The normal way you handle this is to set the inventory hostname to the "friendly" name, and then set `ansible_host` to the ip address. That is, if your inventory script reports a host named "host0", then when called with `--host host0` it should produce:

```
{
  "inventory_hostname": "host0",
  "ansible_host": "10.0.2.6",
}
```

You will see the name `host0` in playbook output, but ansible will use the ip address for connections.

Comment: i changed the inventory script accordingly and it works perfectly!

Comment: this was helpful for me, one note is that the variable should be named `ansible_host` not `ansible_hostname` in the inventory file

Answer (score -1):

An option would be to extend the Dynamic Inventory Scrip to add or replace nodes in an [inventory directory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#using-inventory-directories-and-multiple-inventory-sources). For example in INI format

```
NODE_A ansible_host=10.0.2.6
```